# How to do advanced search in netbeans entire project?

Tags: java, netbeans

Currently I'm working in a project which I have to translate some entire phrases in netbeans web application written on java. When I search using <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> some pages get missing in search output even I'm already open those pages.

Can anyone help me with search deeply in entire netbeans project in netbeans?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What's does 'advancely' mean?

Comment: @EJP advancely means when I search some words the search results don't show it. But it really on jsp page. That kind of advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for text in all open project by `Ctrl + Shift + F`

Comment: Are you sure you've selected correct scope, match case, ignore list and all ??

Comment: That is available on dialogue box which is open while you press `Ctrl + Shift + F`

Comment: I usually try like this and it gives me results some times. But some times results are missing.

Answer (score 0):

For searching: Select the folder your want to search in (so in your case your project folder) and press `Strg + Shift + F` to open the search prompt.

For replacing: Select the folder you want search in and press `Strg + H` to open the replace prompt. (should be much faster than searching for every phrases)

Comment: yeah. That's the one I used. Still no results,